# Grayscale-Brightness to Color-Scale [EMUG.CV?]

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm currently working on a program for measuring pressure optically. I have already programmed the User-Interface and Stuff and I want to know: How do I convert the brightness of a Grayscale to a Colorscale (the brighter the Pixel, the bigger the Pressure, the more red the new Pixel; the darker the Pixel, the lower the Pressure, the more blue the new Pixel)

I hope you guys can help me :-)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  Couldn't you just use RGB for a color and use a certain range (x - 255) for the upper half range of pressure and a similar range for B?  You can just generate your color programmatically after you calculate where along the scale your pressure is.

Answer (score 0):

What linear space do you want to cover?

When pressure is 0, do you want

red = 255 and blue 0, and when the pressure is 255 then red = 0 and blue == 255?

If this is your path, you need a linear interpolation:

Red = 255 - P

Blue = P,
where P is your current pressure

Using this formula you get an interpolation between red and blue ignoring green.